# iOS Firebase Crashlytics not showing up crashes in Dashboard

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I implemented Firebase Crashlytics in my iOS app. I followed all the steps in firebase documentation. I already ran crashlytics without the debugger by closing the app first and then re run the app so that crash reports can be sent. I even get this message

> Crash upload submission succesful

I even added the Run script and set variable to "DWARF with DSYM"

> "${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"

I ready somewhere that if DSYM aren't uploaded you won't see your crashes even if they are uploaded successfully. So I went into my pods/Fabric/ and click on "run" CLI. It clearly says **DSYM not uploaded because GoogleServiceInfo.plist wasn't found**. Although it's there and yes it's included in my target as well as in my bundle.

[image]

Here is the screenshot. I have tried all possible steps to include GoogleService-Info.plist but still when I run manually it says this.

[image]

Any another thing that I can try ?

Comment: Are you sure its GoogleService-Info.plist not GoogleService-Info1.plist or GoogleService-Info2.plist or something else

Comment: Yes rechecked it like 10 times already.

Comment: hi Moaz khan how did you resolve this issue. I am facing the same issue unable to find plist when i run manually. Its working in simulator when i created a ipa file and produce a test crash showing missing dysm

Comment: Just read my answer add the test crash in the first view controller then wait for a while and the tests will start appearing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To someone still struggling with the issue here is what resolved the issue for me.

> 1. I deleted the GoogleService-Info.plist and added it again.
> 2. I tried the crash on my welcome screen rather than in one of the
>      screens of my tab bar controller as I believe from there it's unable
>          to find GoogleServiceInfo.plist file so it worked.

Comment: m having the same issue but it still not get resolved by even deleting and re-adding GoogleService-Info.plist. Its' a bit frustrating now.

Comment: Add a test crash in the first view controller of your app. After that it will start to show up.

Answer (score 39):

Try this:

1. Run your app from Xcode to install it on the simulator or your
   device
2. Press the Stop button in Xcode to quit it
3. Launch your app
   from the home screen to run it without the debugger
4. Press the “Crash” button to trigger the crash
5. Run the app again from Xcode so it can deliver the recorded crash to Crashlytics
6. Within a few minutes, you should see the crash appear on your Firebase
   Crashlytics Console.

For reference:

[Integrating Firebase and Crashlytics in iOS](https://medium.com/@piero9212/integrating-firebase-and-crashlytics-in-ios-complete-guide-updated-2019-4526e9ab9c6d?source=friends_link&sk=3f9605587cfadc6a56f35cabf5ac2e82)

Comment: hey, this is working on my case, but after set user details using sample codes are providing by fabric, new crashes are not showing in dashboard and there has warning with Missing dSYMs, why is that ? where is wrong

Comment: @SachinthaUdara try this:

Check if Xcode is producing debug symbol files:
1. Open your project in Xcode, and select the project file in the Xcode Navigator.
2. Select your main build target from the Select a project or target dropdown.
3. Open the target's Build Settings tab.
4. Click All near the top of the tab.
5. Search for "debug information format".
6. Set Debug Information Format to DWARF with dSYM File.

If that doesn't work, you should add a run upload symbols script manually

For reference: 

https://medium.com/swlh/firebase-crashlytics-full-guide-part2-52b35c3c79c8

Comment: Thanks of your reply, Yes I have done dSYM selecting a part in early of configuration. I don`t know the real reason for it, but when I did the same thing in firebase it work calm. I think this is wrong with fabric SDK.

Comment: OMG, I spent a day trying to figure this out and this is the only thing that worked! Thanks.

Comment: i was missing the step 5 -> it's important to relaunch the app with xcode and not from the home screen. thanks a lot !

Comment: Firebase Crashlytics is obsolete I think, It doesn't work anymore... Impossible to make it work

Answer (score 13):

I have tried serval things but below steps are worked for me

1. Put `FirebaseApp.configure()` to first line of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
2. If you have both `Firebase/Crashlytics` and `Crashlytics`. Removed `Crashlytics` from pods and update it
3. Check in Build Phases `Run Script` if you have entry fot `"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"`.
4. If you're running app in debug mode make sure you have added `-FIRDebugEnabled` in Project's test scheme.
5. Run the App From Home Screen(Don't run it from Xcode) and crash it on any button's Action.(you will find the crash in Firebase Console with in 5-10 mins)

Comment: thanks man, I was trying to understand why activation does not occur, it turns out that you need to launch the application from the home screen, it's a shame that Google cannot write about this in its manual

Comment: I have `Crashlytics`, `Fabric` and `Firebase/Crashlytics` so it was confused. I removed all and keep only `Firebase/Crashlytics` and it worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This part did it for me: 
5. Run the App From Home Screen(Don't run it from Xcode) and crash it on any button's Action.(you will find the crash in Firebase Console with in 5-10 mins)

Comment: While adding this (-FIRDebugEnabled) into the edit schema please make sure you include with minus/hyphen symbol.
Thanks, you have saved my life @Sahil

Answer (score 5):

After following all the steps as stated in the docs followed below steps:

- Install app using xcode.
- Quit the app.
- Launch the app from home screen - This is important
- Force a crash

They starting showing on the console.

Comment: Did not work for me sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I solving the same issue adding the `FirebaseCraslytics` pod to my `Podfile`:

```
...
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics'
```

Then I added the following `Run Script` in the `Build Phases`:

[image]

Script:

```bash
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
```

Input Files:

```
$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)
$(SRCROOT)/${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}
```

After that, I followed the [Step 3: Force a test crash to finish setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios#force-test-crash) and `Crashlytics` start to working.

Comment: I did everything, but I think Firebase Crashlytics doesn't work anymore...

Answer (score 0):

After following all the necessary steps:
NOT running the app from Xcode, but from iPhone/simulator interface helped me detect the crash in Crashlytics dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

For SwiftUI and Swift 5 paste below code to under of Buid Phases

Script:

> "${BUILD_DIR%/Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run"

[image]

Answer (score -4):

When I have this issue, I do a manual install and yes first use the Fabric app to initialise the app into their system - https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/manual-install