# Firebase Crashlytics is not working in iOS

Tags: ios

Implemented all steps from firebase doc :

1. Create App on firebase
2. add google plist in project
3. POD installed
4. Add `FirebaseApp.configure()` in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
5. Added run script `${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run`
6. update Debug information format

Comment: try generating a forced crash and check on Firebase console.

Comment: I already crash application forcefully. but no count on firebase console

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ..........................................??????

Comment: Maybe the solution is here! https://stackoverflow.com/a/56800623/2342915 
First, you need to build the app and launch the app with Xcode, next launch without attaching with Xcode, then launch with Xcode and the app will send the traces.. 

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure Firebase configuration should be first line in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of AppDelegate file.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
   FirebaseApp.configure()
   Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true
   return true
 }
```

Comment: Yes i used same.