# Fabric Crashlytics not working. iOS 14 app/XCode 12

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

Firebase integration with my app is working like a charm.
So I tried to add Crashlytics.
After pod the SDK and configuring my app in XCode, I've got the version message on log:
"2020-10-23 14:13:36.386002-0300 Findn[44158:3074710] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 4.6.2"

But at Firebase Console there isn't a card for Crashlytics.
And at Crashlytics tab this circle keep spinning.

Any tips?

[image: message at crashlytics tab on firebase console]

EDIT:

Guess I wasn't clear enough, sorry.
I did follow all guidelines to integrate Firebase to my app.
The problem seems to be on Firebase side, since my app's log does not report any errors on xcode.

Comment: Any solutions now?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Now you can not use fabric solely. You have to integrate firebase to use a fabric.
Check this link:
[firebase crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56800623/2342915)!

The steps are the following:

- Ensure you add the code in order to force a crash, something like that [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?authuser=0)
- First, you need to build the app and launch the app with Xcode,
- Next launch without attaching with Xcode (manually, tapping on icon app), and force crash app with `fatalError()`
- Then launch with Xcode and the app will send the traces...